# HiveServer2 throughput issue on more than 100 connections

Tags: hive, emr, parquet

I am using Hive on Amazon EMR for ETL of CSV data into Parquet data (and applying a strongly typed schema).  I am connecting from my SQS listener application to HiveServer2 using thrift with up to 250 open connections.

An ETL looks like: SET parameters, CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE (source), CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE (destination), INSERT OVERRIDE, DROP TABLEs

When running ~100 or less ETLs at a time the performance of the SET, CREATE, and DROP statements are subsecond.  The INSERT takes ~100 seconds via a MR job.

Now when I ramp this up to ~250 ETLs at a time the performance of the SET, CREATE, and DROP statement gets orders of magnitude worse.  It almost looks like these simple statements are getting stuck behind the INSERT statements even though each ETL is on a separate connection.

I tried increasing `hive.server2.async.exec.threads` and `hive.server2.async.exec.wait.queue.size` but I don't see a difference.  Am I missing some other tunable configuration?

I am basically unable to push enough jobs through to occupy the cluster resources.  I know batching is a strategy, but I would like to keep the liveliness of my data.

Comment: Did you check the Thrift connections from HS2 to Metastore? The JDBC connection pool from Metastore to its back-end DB? The Garbage Collector stats (in both HS2 and Metastore services)? Also, did you try to set up *multiple* HS2 instances in parallel?

Comment: Check Cloudera rule-of-thumb advice at https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-10-x/topics/admin_hive_tuning.html#id_umf_bmk_nw

Comment: HS2 -> Metastore looks to be running ~160ish connections.  Metastore -> MariaDB are ~18 connections.  What is the configuration key for the metastore pool when talking to its backend DB?
I haven't pursued the HAProxy approach to doing 2 HS2 instances in parallel because Amazon EMR is a little different and everything is on a single instance. 
Garbage collection looked ok for metastore (no full gc) since it has plenty of memory and using little of it.